# Firebase listener onAuthStateChanged not triggered on S3 Website

Tags: firebase, amazon-s3, oauth, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I simply re-implemented OAUTH2 with Instagram and Firebase with the serverless framework. I took inspiration from this project:
https://github.com/firebase/custom-auth-samples/tree/master/instagram
I am hosting the main page `index.html` on a public S3 bucket.

My API functions are good, I am receiving the exact same content as with my local testing with the repository above. I have all the tokens that my app need (instagram token, firebase token...) so it looks all good from a server perspective.

The last call is returning this piece of HTML:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.0/firebase.js" </script>
<script>
  var token = 'firebase_token_yyy';
  var config = {
    apiKey: 'firebase_api_key_xxx'
  };
  var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
  app.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).then(function() {
    window.close();
  });
</script>
```

This is well executed as it is closing the pop-up for logging.

However, `onAuthStateChanged` is not triggered (https://github.com/firebase/custom-auth-samples/blob/master/instagram/public/main.js#L41).
This is weird since the `main.js` code was well initialized when opening `index.html`.

I also tried running a simple manual web server: same behavior.

Would it be related to AWS S3 ?
I also though that the browser would propagate the state across windows ?

There is no javascript error and the hostname was whitelisted for Firebase Oauth.

Comment: Note, I recommend you update to the latest version of firebase.js. It the popup where the signInWithCustomToken occurs a different domain than the page that opened it? where the onAuthStateChanges listener is happening.

Comment: thanks great catch, it was a domain issue!